# How to get the ID of user that has started the process in Activiti from a script Groovy?

Tags: groovy, activiti

In a Groovy Script step, I do need to get the user ID that has started the process. As this script is the first step in workflow, maybe getting the "current logged user" could do the work. But in both cases I didn't manage to get it working.

I'm using Activiti 5.22.

Documentation brings that should have this variable "authenticatedUserId" that should have this data, but if I try to use it in the script, it breaks because it has no definition.